# Powershell PSDrive Not working under Scheduled Task

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task

I am trying to move files from a DMZ server to a domain server via powershell I can get it to work from an interactive session however if I try to run it under a scheduled task the copy fails.  I added transcript start command to try and see what might be happening but I am not sure how to troubleshoot it.  Are you not allowed to run PSDrive within a Scheduled Task?

```
Start-Transcript -path C:\temp\pslog.txt -append -NoClobber -IncludeInvocationHeader 

$password = convertto-securestring -String 'somepassword' -AsPlainText -Force
#$pass = Get-Content C:\ITScripts\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('username@domain', $password)
#$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "username@domain",$pass
 
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\DOMAINSERVER\FOLDERNAME" -Credential $creds
Get-ChildItem "LOCALPATH" -Filter *.txt | Move-Item -Destination "Z:\Inbound" -Force -PassThru

Remove-PSDrive Z

Stop-Transcript
```

So if I run this from the desktop or a powershell session it works ok when I run it from a scheduled task I get the following output.

---

Transcript started, output file is C:\temp\pslog.txt

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\DOMAINSERVER\FOLDERNAME" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At C:\ITScripts\CopyFilesBetweenServer.ps1:11 char:1

- New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\DOMAINSERVER\FOLDERNAME ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (Z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
  ```

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\DOMAINSERVER\FOLDERNAME" either does not exist,
or it is not a folder.
At C:\ITScripts\CopyFilesBetweenServer.ps1:11 char:1

- New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\DOMAINSERVER\FOLDERNAME ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (Z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
  ```

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist.
At C:\ITScripts\CopyFilesBetweenServer.ps1:14 char:1

- Remove-PSDrive Z
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Z:String) [Remove-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand
  ```

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist.
At C:\ITScripts\CopyFilesBetweenServer.ps1:14 char:1

- Remove-PSDrive Z
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Z:String) [Remove-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand
  ```

---

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Notice that some of your unc paths start with a single slash...those don't work.  The ones with 2 slashes work.

Comment: Yeah that is just on the transcript output and is my fault as I was removing the real names.  The code snippet is \\

Comment: Is the scheduled task running as an account that has access to the network paths in question?

Comment: No the server is not domain joined so I have used the -Credential switch pass through a domain account that has access to the mapped drive.  The scheduled task at the moment is running with a local admin account.

Comment: If you dump the credentials to disk from PowerShell, using Export-CliXml under the account which is running the scheduled task, and then import the credentials using Import-CliXML does that work? The credentials would only be readable on that machine, using that account, so you can't just copy/paste the credential file.